# How can I automatically restart a Windows service if it crashes?

Tags: windows, windows-service

I have a Windows service that exits unexpectedly every few days. Is there a simple way to monitor it to make sure it gets restarted quickly if it crashes?

Answer (score 96):

Under the Services application, select the properties of the service in question.

View the recovery tab - there are all sorts of options - I'd set First & Second Failure to Restart the Service, Third to run a batch program that [BLAT](http://www.blat.net/)'s out an email with the third failure notification.

You should also set the Reset Fail Count to 1 to reset the fail count daily.

**EDIT:**

Looks like you can do this via a command line:

```
SC failure w3svc reset= 432000  actions= restart/30000/restart/60000/run/60000
SC failure w3svc command= "MyBatchFile.cmd"
```

Your MyBatchFile.CMD file can look like this:

```
blat - -body "Service W3svc Failed" -subject "SERVICE ERROR" -to Notify@Example.com -server SMTP.Example.com -f Administrator@Example.com
```

Comment: All good stuff, but +1 especially for the email notification advice and the command-line stuff.

Comment: Where should the batch file live on disk?

Comment: Anywhere.  With `SC failure w3svc command= "MyBatchFile.cmd"` it should be in the path or C:\Windows\System32.  You can put it in any directory if you use a full path i.e. `SC failure w3svc command= "c:\Stuff\MyBatchFile.cmd"`

Comment: Chrissy LeMaire has a script that wraps this in powershell: https://blog.netnerds.net/2020/05/windows-services-recovery-for-sql-server/ for multiple servers.

Answer (score 10):

Open Services.msc, double-click on the service to open the Properties of the service, there is a Recovery tab and those settings should allow you to restart the service upon failure.

Answer (score 9):

Try to set recover time to zero:

[image]

The command line equivalent:

`SC failure YOUR_SERVICE_NAME reset= 0 actions= restart/0/restart/0/restart/0`

Anyway sometimes auto recover doesn't work correctly and it recommended to use third party software. It seems when service exit gracefully with exit code of 0 windows don't try to recover it.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar requirement to start a service if stopped. The simplest solution I thought was to execute the below command in windows task scheduler every 5 minutes:

net start MyServiceName

This command will basically start the service (if stopped) and has no effect if the service is already running.

Answer (score 1):

I am using [ServiceKeeper](http://www.servicekeeper.com) on my windows 2008 server at HostForLife.eu and it works very good. Previously, I had a review on ServiceHawk, but I prefer to use ServiceKeeper for its easier management and interface.

Answer (score 1):

I recently implemented a recovery option to run a powershell script that attempts to restart the service a defined number of times and sends an email notification at the conclusion, it also .

After several attempts (and despite all the other things I have seen) The configuration of fields on the recovery tab in services is as follows:

Program: Powershell.exe
   **Not C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Powershell.exe

Command line parameters: -command "& {SomePath\YourScript.ps1 '$args[0]' '$args[1]' '$args[n]'}"

eg: -command "& {C:\PowershellScripts\ServicesRecovery.ps1 'Service Name'}"

**The $args are parameters that will be passed to your script. These are not required.

here is the powershell script:

```
cd $PSScriptRoot

$n = $args[0]

function CreateLogFile {
$events = Get-EventLog -LogName Application -Source SomeSource -Newest 40
if (!(Test-Path "c:\temp")) {
    New-Item -Path "c:\temp" -Type directory}
if (!(Test-Path "c:\temp\ServicesLogs.txt")) {
    New-Item -Path "c:\temp" -Type File -Name "ServicesLogs.txt"}
    $events | Out-File -width 600 c:\temp\ServicesLogs.txt
}

function SendEmail  {
$EmailServer = "SMTP Server"
$ToAddress = "Name@domain.com"
$FromAddress = "Name@domain.com"

CreateLogFile

$Retrycount = $Retrycount + 1
send-mailmessage -SmtpServer $EmailServer -Priority High -To $ToAddress -From $FromAddress -Subject "$n Service failure" `
-Body "The $n service on server $env:COMPUTERNAME has stopped and was unable to be restarted after $Retrycount attempts." -Attachments c:\temp\ServicesLogs.txt

Remove-Item "c:\temp\ServicesLogs.txt"
}

function SendEmailFail  {
$EmailServer = "SMTP Server"
$ToAddress = "Name@domain.com"
$FromAddress = "Name@domain.com"

CreateLogFile

$Retrycount = $Retrycount + 1
send-mailmessage -SmtpServer $EmailServer -Priority High -To $ToAddress -From $FromAddress -Subject "$n Service Restarted" `
-Body "The $n service on server $env:COMPUTERNAME stopped and was successfully restarted after $Retrycount attempts. The relevant system logs are attached." -Attachments c:\temp\ServicesLogs.txt

Remove-Item "c:\temp\ServicesLogs.txt"
}

function StartService {

$Stoploop = $false

do {
   if ($Retrycount -gt 3){
     $Stoploop = $true
     SendEmail
     Break
    }

   $i =  Get-WmiObject win32_service | ?{$_.Name -imatch $n} | select Name, State, StartMode
    if ($i.State -ne "Running" -and $i.StartMode -ne "Disabled") {

        sc.exe start $n
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 35

        $i =  Get-WmiObject win32_service | ?{$_.Name -imatch $n} | select State
          if ($i.state -eq "Running"){
              $Stoploop = $true
              SendEmailFail}
          else {$Retrycount = $Retrycount + 1}
    }        
}
While ($Stoploop -eq $false)
}

[int]$Retrycount = "0"
StartService
```

Answer (score 0):

This was my answer on a similar [thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/30842/print-spooler-service-does-not-restart) Hope this helps...

You can schedule a simple vbs script like this one to restart periodically the service on the computer if needed.

```
strComputer = "." 
strSvcName = "YOUR_SERVICE_NAME" 
set objWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
set objService = objWMI.Get("Win32_Service.Name='" & strSvcName & "'")
If objService.State= "Stopped" Then
    objService.StartService()
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Someone asked a similar question over at Super User:  You could install a tool that monitors windows services. Something like [Service Hawk](http://www.servicehawk.com) would help you keep the services started, or allow you to schedule automatic restarts (possibly during the night) to keep the service running smoothly.

Answer (score -3):

Following youtube video may help you to restart the windows services automatically

https://youtu.be/MK1akShoeY8